# How to Merge & Dedupe Worksheets Dynamically?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm designing a system to track inventory across multiple properties and storage facilities.  Each property and storage facility will have their own worksheet.  In some cases a single storage facility will have multiple properties associated with it.  I'd like to be able to easily link multiple properties to a single storage facility and pull in the data for the storage facility worksheet from those worksheets.

So here's an example of inventory for Property A:
[image]

There is a similar list of inventory for Property B.  The columns in red need to be combined into the worksheet for Storage Facility 1.  If both properties have, for example, shampoo, I don't want 'shampoo' to show up on the combined inventory list twice.

I'd like to be able to do calculations and vlookups and such in this new worksheet with the combined inventory lists.  I think it'll need some kind of Dynamic Array magic, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem here is that you are entering data into a report structure (one sheet per facility) and then you want to report across the data from all these reports. That is fraught with difficulty.

It would be way easier to enter the data into a flat table and use another sheet to build a report where you can filter for each facility. Enter the data with all the duplicates, using a column to identify the facility.

Then build an inventory report with a pivot table, which will by default list only unique items.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel there is no built-in function can quickly merge sheets and remove duplicates.
The method is to copy and paste the first sheet contents one by one then apply the
Remove Duplicates function to remove the duplicates.

- Select all the contents in Sheet1
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the contents
- Go to sheet2 and place the cursor at its end
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste
- Select the combined contents
- Click *Data > Remove Duplicates*
- In the Remove Duplicates dialog, check or uncheck data headers as need, keeping
  all columns checked
- Click OK twice
- The sheets have now been combined with all duplicates removed.